# what is the best way to set up a Production server for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am setting up a new SharePoint  production Environment, i need the recommended or best practice methods on the software and hardware specifications for big a enterprise environment. i want to create a separate server for Sql content databases,Production server and Development(not necessarily important) i need clearance on how many HHD i should put in the production server and how i can implement load balancing,so that i can set a well implemented farm environment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need details of how many hard drives you require?  For a full enterprise level deployment there would be multiple different servers.  You would have web front end servers, application servers, analytics servers  all running Sharepoint in addition to the Database Server(s).

If you are really looking to max things out then one SSD for the OS, one for the pagefile, one for the applications, all striped in RAID.  But that is more than likely over the top and you can just have a a single SSD in regular RAID for your application server.  Then implement a HSM solution on the database server.

In order to give a better answer can you detail a few things

1. How many users you anticipate
2. If they are distributed or all on the LAN
3. How many site collections and sites you expect to host
4. The size of your overall content - i.e. are you including gigabytes of video
5. Whether you intend to use any Office Web Apps later on

Have a look here : http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/B/F/3BF70FE5-83FD-4A26-AC19-EBF94EE312E5/SharePtServDeployment.pdf

Comment: Thank ypu So much your link truly helped we managed to come to an agreement with my clients about specifications with the help of microsoft best practises for sharePoint deployment and your article helped me a lot, thank you